# Activating mel script or global proc during attribute change

Tags: mel

I have developed a hand IKFK snap tool for my character but, if have to run that script , i have to copy paste that script editor to run it  or use shelf button to activate it.

Is there any way that i can run the command, if i change my attribute Value From Ik to Fk in my attribute editor itself

sorry for my English (R.I.P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a [scriptJob](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/scriptJob-html.html) to run a script when some event happens. AtributeChange is one such event.. there are plenty others.

```
global proc ikfkSnap() {
    int $val = `getAttr "mySkelControl.switchIkFk"`;
    print ("changing ik/fk mode to "+ $val);
    // ....
}

int $scriptJobNum = `scriptJob -attributeChange "mySkelControl.switchIkFk" "ikfkSnap" `;
```